# Why I can't paste a mirrored version on certain axis?

Tags: animation, actions

I am new to blender and started creating a character of an online template some time ago. I am currently on the animating phase and I am making a walk action. I was following an online tutorial [Video]. I was going to paste the mirrored copied key frames but I could only paste it mirrored on the x-axis, and not on the y-axis which is what I need.

[image: An Image (:]

Comment: change everything to be symetric on the x axis since that is the standard. I really dont know if there is a different solution

Comment: so I just rotate the entire figure?

Comment: yes you do. But keep in mind you have to do it in editmode

Comment: Can you make it a post so I can mark it as done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the Mirror Copy, your model needs to be symetric along the X-axis. To achieve that you have to rotate your model and your armature in Edit Mode and possibly change your Mirror Modifier on your model to mirror along the X axis.